# Can I acquire 2+ locks at the same time in python

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

Can I acquire 2 or more locks at the same time in python directly?

```
from thread import allocate_lock, start_new_thread

def A_thread( A_lock ):
   while 1:
       with A_lock:
           pass # assume complex code here


def B_thread( B_lock ):
   while 1:
       with B_lock:
           pass # assume complex code here

A_lock = allocate_lock()
B_lock = allocate_lock()

A_thread = start_new_thread( A_thread, ( A_lock, ) )
B_thread = start_new_thread( B_thread, ( B_lock, ) )

while 1:
    with A_lock and B_lock:
        pass # assume complex code here
```

s.t. both A_lock and B_lock should be granted at the same time or neither of them.

I don't want to acquire locks in the same order and acquire `A_lock` when I need only `B_lock` (i.e. in `def B_thread(...)`)

The issue of the code above is fairness between `A_thread` and `B_thread`. Since `main` thread acquire `A_lock` first, `A_thread` has lower priority over `B_thread`

---

Probably, better example will be

```
from thread import allocate_lock, start_new_thread

def A_thread( A_lock, B_lock ):
   while 1:
       with B_lock and A_lock:
           pass # assume complex code here



A_lock = allocate_lock()
B_lock = allocate_lock()

A_thread = start_new_thread( A_thread, ( A_lock, B_lock ) )

while 1:
    with A_lock and B_lock:
        pass # assume complex code here
```

The issue here is `busy waiting`, if both `main` and `A` thread acquire their 1st lock before one of them acquire its 2nd lock, 1st thread that acquires its 2nd lock will force the other thread to start its `with` statement from the beginning. In addition, the thread that gets 2nd lock first may run next again ( `thread fairness` issue)

Comment: I think now that the answer is no. 2+ locks cannot be acquired at the same time directly. Either a programmer should acquire locks in a specific order or cycle cpu w/o real reason in certain rare cases.

Comment: I don't think that `with` supports it this way. but we can nest `with` blocks or manually call `acquire` method of each lock sequentially and the `release` methods of each later.